# extract files HTC rom

Tags: custom-roms, rom

I have installed cyanogenmod in my htc wildfire recently. I made a nand backup of the previous ROM and I need some stuff that I didnt back up. Is there any way to extract files from the ROM without reinstalling it on my phone? I tried to mount it on a linux machine but I dont know which filesystem it uses.

In case it is useful, what I need are some pictures that I thought that were in the sd card and apparently they were in the internal memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, [Nandroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830) uses the yaffs2 file system for storing backups inside the .img files.

A quick search on Google points to [these instructions](http://mdzlog.alcor.net/2010/05/29/extracting-files-from-a-nandroid-backup-using-unyaffs/) on extracting files from a Nandroid backup:

First you will need to download and build the "unyaffs" module:

```
svn checkout http://unyaffs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ unyaffs
cd unyaffs
gcc -o unyaffs unyaffs.c
```

Then copy the image file off your phone's Nandroid directory and extract it:

```
mkdir data && cd data
~/src/android/unyaffs/unyaffs /[path-to-backup-folder]/data.img
```

Comment: the svn is not working so I downloaded the files from browser. Still unyaffs worked without problems